# Kendo.Mvc.dll deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, kendo-ui

I have run into a problem with Kendo.Mvc.dll, I have a MVC 4 application which uses Kendo DataSourceRequest object to export the grid in excel format. The application works great when I run it using visual studios. But when I publish it in IIS 7.5 it gives me a internal server error. When I commented the code that uses Kendo.Mvc.dll and republished it, the application worked properly again. Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score -2):

you need to deploy the Kendo.Mvc.dll too.

1. in your ASP.NET MVC project goto references
2. click on Kendo.Mvc
3. change "local copy" to true in the properties window
4. redeploy your app
5. verify that Kendo.Mvc.dll is now in your /bin directory
6. your done :)